# old apps using xcode 4.5 not able to align center

Tags: position, alignment, ios6, retina-display, xcode4.5

I wonder if any of you encounter this, I just upgrade my Xcode to Xcode 4.5, before it asked to add the `Default-568h@2x.png` screen, my apps could be aligned in center position on iPhone 5.  However, it seem like a must add that screen, so I added and rebuilt my app. The apps align to left.

I know I can make a new set of graphic `1136x640px` and write code to adjust the alignment but I have over 20 apps.  Can someone tell me if there is any possible way that make the app (used to build by previous Xcode) be aligned center automatically?

I didn't check the option Auto Layout.  Even when I did, it didn't help to align the app in center position.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the Default-568h@2x.png launch screen image, the compatibility letterboxing mode will take effect. Having this image triggers the phone to assume all of your layouts are compatible with the new screen size.

Comment: yes i removed the Default-568h@2x.png after i added it, but it remain the same, it still align to left.

Comment: even worse is that, after i removed the Default-568h@2x.png, its stretch the old 480x320 default.png to 1130x640, so everything align to left.